# Xamarin Forms UWP Project cant connect to external service (localhost working)

Tags: c#, rest, uwp, xamarin.forms

I was testing my application, which is using a RESTful service. So far so good. I have deployed my service to aszure and everything works fine. The problem now is, that my UWP-Application is refusing to connect to the service.

I am using a HTTPClient

```
Client = new HttpClient();
Client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

var response = Client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
```

The Client.GetAsync throws me a exception.

I have set the Capabilities in the Package.appxmanifest (Internet & Private Networks)

Exception:

```
Count = error CS0103: The name 'InnerExceptionCount' does not exist in the current context
```

InnerException:

```
{"Der Text zu diesem Fehlercode wurde nicht gefunden.\r\n\r\nDie Serververbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden.\r\n"}
```

The InnecException is german and means "The text to this Errorcode was not found. Could not connect to the Server."

It is really weird that I get this exception while using another service than localhost, if I use localhost, everything works fine as it should. Do you have any suggestions?

Screenshot Package.appxmanifest (UWP):

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

Comment: I have the same issue, do you found a solution? (gleiche Fehlermeldung ;))

Answer (score 0):

Not really the right way to do an async call

```
var response = await Client.GetAsync(uri);
```

I am assuming the service is returning a response for the url you are "getting" from

Comment: the .Result awaits it too